# Backtesting trading strategy using backtesting.py

Tags: python, trading, back-testing

> I want to backtest a trading strategy. Its relatively simple.  Just
>   buy a stock at a start price. Immediately set a sell order at an exit
>   difference above and a buy order at an entry difference below. I want
>   it to continue till a max open lot number of times. I have managed to
>   write code below. The orders are places but none execute. I am using
>   the backtesting.py library
>   https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/doc/backtesting/index.html
>   Example: start = 125 orders should be placed at buy 124, sell 126..buy
>   125, sell 127..buy 126, sell 128 and so on. The next function runs for
>   every new row of the data and it there that i am having trouble to set
>   my current buy and sell prices. Help anyone please

````
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy, Position
from backtesting.lib import crossover, SignalStrategy
from backtesting.test import SMA

class Scalp_buy(Strategy):

    start = 125
    lot_step = 5
    buy_criteria = 1
    sell_criteria = 1
    max_open = 10
    lot_size = 6000
    max_loss = 1000
    equity_list = []
    current_buy_order = []
    current_sell_order = []
    current_buy = start - buy_criteria
    current_sell = start + sell_criteria

    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.current_buy = self.start - self.buy_criteria
        self.current_sell = self.start + self.sell_criteria
        self.buy(price = self.start, tp = self.current_sell)

    def next(self):
        super().next()
        for x in range(0,self.max_open): 
            self.orders.set_entry(price = self.current_buy)
            self.orders.set_tp(price = self.current_sell)
            self.current_buy  += self.buy_criteria
            self.current_sell  += self.sell_criteria

       # print(self.position.open_time,self.position.open_price,self.position.pl, self.position.pl_pct , self.position.size)


bt = Backtest(df, Scalp_buy, cash=10000, commission=.0014)

output = bt.run()
output```
````

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/doc/backtesting/backtesting.html#gsc.tab=0)

If `trade_on_close` is `True`, market orders will be filled with respect to the current bar's closing price instead of the next bar's open.

you should use `Backtest` with param `trade_on_close=True`

```
bt = Backtest(df, Scalp_buy, cash=10000, commission=.0014, trade_on_close=True)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding the link which is missing.